# Moving values from one table to another

Tags: jquery, html, spring, axios

I am displaying my data from mysql to a table using spring, axios and vue Js. When I click the data in my table row I am able to alert the data. What I want is when I click the data it should appear or move to another different table or list within the same page.How can I go about this. Here is my code:

```
<table id="myTable" class="display table" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Type</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="account in accounts">
      <td>{{account.account_type}}</td>
      <td>{{account.amount}}</td>
      <td>{{account.date}}</td>
      <td>{{account.description}}</td>
      <td><Button v-on:click.prevent="getRowData(account)">Add To List</Button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var appVM = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          id: '',
          account_type: '',
          amount: '',
          date: '',
          description: '',
          accounts: Array(),
          rowData: {}

        },
        created: function() {
          this.getAccounts();
        },
        getRowData: function(account) {
          axios.get("/account/" + account.id, ).then(function(response) {
            this.rowData = response.data;
            alert(JSON.stringify(this.rowData))
          }.bind(this))
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the data again outside of the table, you can just display `rowData` (I don't know the structure):

```
<div v-if="rowData">
  <div> {{rowData.accountId}} </div>
  <div> {{rowData.whatever}} </div>
</div>
```

If you want to show the list of clicked rows:
1) declare in

```
data: {
...
clickedAccounts: Array()
}
```

2) push the new elements when you alert it:
clickedAccounts.push(this.rowData)

3) Show it in the table or something like this

```
<div v-for="clickedAccount in clickedAccounts">
  <div> {{clickedAccount.accountId}} </div>
  <div> {{clickedAccount.whatever}} </div>
</div>
```

4) And maybe the most important: **think, search and try :)**

Comment: Thanks for the response I have tried but it when I click it over writes the previous data

Comment: You're welcome. What does it mean: It writes the previous data? Is it displaying the same data that you have in the alert?

Comment: I mean that when I click it does not add another row. It only replaces the existing record

Comment: If you to show the list and not the last element, the create another array and when you click, you can push the new element into the list, I've updated the answer